# ORA-00904: invalid identifier 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier"

Tags: sql, oracle

When running the query in sqldeveloper, I get the *"%s: invalid identifier"* error. Basically I want to concatenate two columns from TABLE 1 and compare it with one column in TABLE 2. Two tables are from two different databases. For some reason, it does not like the t1_Name alias.

```
select t1.First_name ||' '|| t1.Last_Name as t1_Name, t2.*
from table1 t1, table2 t2
where t1.t1_Name = t2.Account_name;
```

Any feedback would be appreciated on how I can fix this.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use an alias defined in the `SELECT` list of a query in the `WHERE` clause.  Logically, the `WHERE` clause is processed first so the alias doesn't exist yet.

You'd either need to replicate the calculation

```
select t1.First_name ||' '|| t1.Last_Name as t1_Name, t2.*
  from table1 t1, table2 t2
 where t1.First_name ||' '|| t1.Last_Name = t2.Account_name;
```

or you would need to define the alias in an inline view

```
select t1.t1_name, t2.*
  from (select t1.First_name ||' '|| t1.Last_Name as t1_Name
          from table1 t1) t1
       join table2 t2
         on( t1.t1_name = t2.account_name )
```

Answer (score 0):

If your two tables are in different databases, your have to use a database link. Assume table1 is in database db1 and table2 is in database db2. Your query (assuming you run the query on db1) should look like that:

```
SELECT t1.First_name ||' '|| t1.Last_Name as t1_Name, t2.* 
  FROM table1 t1, table2@db2 t2 WHERE t1.t1_Name = t2.Account_name;
```

More information you can find here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts002.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub select:

```
select * 
  from (select t1.First_name ||' '|| t1.Last_Name t1_Name, t2.*
         from table1 t1, table2 t2)
 where t1_Name = Account_name;
```

Check out [this Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1ae56/6).